# What am I missing: Intergrating custom domain with heroku app + cloudflare not working

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I'm trying to connect my herokuapp to my custom domain, and I'm having tons of problems, I'm stuck at this error Error 525.

I generated an SSL certificate with Cloudflare and installed the certificate, but I still get this error. 
[image]

My [site](https://sororitie.com) points to the cloudflare IP address, but I need to to point to my [herokuapp](https://sororiti.herokuapp.com)

Can someone please help ? Here's my cloudflare details: 
[image]

Comment: maybe have a look here https://thoughtbot.com/blog/set-up-cloudflare-free-ssl-on-heroku

Comment: Thank you, tried out something that I hadn't factored in but the error still persists